# insert form values to database table using wordpress 4.7

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am new in WordPress. I am trying to insert form data to database table(pack).
how to insert data values to database table..Iam not using any plugins.just create a registration form (name,age,address).how to insert these values to table using mysql query.

after submition to see page not found.

using design and process code in samepage

Comment: Use [`$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Comment: <?php
if($_POST['submit']) {
    global $wpdb;
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $offer=$_POST['offer'];
    $prize=$_POST['prize'];
    if($wpdb->insert(
            'pack',
            array( 'name'=>$name,'offer'=>$offer,'prize'=>$prize)) ) };
    ?> iam use this code to insert values to table

Comment: <form name="reg" action="" method="post">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <label>Offer:</label>
        <input type="text" name="offer" id="offer">
        <label>Prize:</label>
        <input type="text" name="prize" id="prize">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>  design page and process code in same page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this may help you a better**

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){    
    global $wpdb;
    $tablename=$wpdb->prefix.'pack';    
    $data=array(
        'name' => $_POST['name'], 
        'age' => $_POST['age'],
        'adrress' => $_POST['adrress'], 
         );
     $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data,array( '%s', '%s', '%s' ));
}    
?>
```

Comment: sir i have doute..how to connect to database?. if any request_once(''); use?? iam not using any thing.

Comment: yes you have to load config file of wordpress like 
require_once('/wp-config.php');

Comment: but siri gotpage not found error and not save to database table.

Comment: my form and process create wed.php file inside theme folder and im go to dashbord to add new page (wed) andselectmy template (wed), then publish .and view page (http://localhost/wordpress/wed/) i can see my form ,and iam fill the fields and submit ,display page not found in same url.

Comment: you have to create a template inside theme folder and your custom form will design init and from wp-admin create page and choose template which you created for form.

Comment: yes sir. iam done the same as.i can see the form fields and submit button.iam fill the fields and submit .go to page not found.

Comment: can you share ftp with me so i can help you in a better way

Comment: <?php / *Template Name:Wed */ ?>
 <form  action="" method="post"><label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><label>Offer:</label><input type="text" name="offer" id="offer"><label>Prize:</label<input type="text" name="prize" id="prize"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>
<?php require_once('../wp-config.php');
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){ global $wpdb;
    $tablename=$wpdb->prefix.'pack';    
    $data=array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'offer' => $_POST['offer'],'prize' => $_POST['prize'], );
     $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data);} ?>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145674/discussion-between-ipscr-and-niraj-patel).